# How to unload DLL itself correctly?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, dll-injection

I make a DLL injection to a process after **ntdll.dll** loading.
Then, in **DllMain** (**DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH** event case) I call [LdrRegisterDllNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/devnotes/ldrregisterdllnotification) and wait when the specific DLL will be loaded (e.g. **statistic.dll**) which functions I want to hook.
If **statistic.dll** wasn't loaded I need to unload injected DLL from the process.

The main question is: How to unload injected DLL correctly?

I wanted to implement it via different thread which will check (after some time) **statistic.dll** library in the process (or specific flag which I can set after the **statistic.dll** loading) and unload injected DLL if it wasn't loaded. But as I know, we can't create a thread in DllMain.

Comment: "*as I know, we can't create a thread in DllMain*" - yes, you can. Just don't have DllMain wait on the thread, or make the thread wait on Dllmain. That is what is problematic, not the act of creating a thread.

Comment: you can create own thread and at the end of it must call [`FreeLibraryAndExitThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibraryandexitthread)

Comment: Thanks guys. I had doubt about creating a thread and wanted to listen alternative opinion about consequences of that. I implemented unloading dll itself via FreeLibraryAndExitThread and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

To unload your DLL use [FreeLibraryAndExitThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibraryandexitthread), make sure you have disconnected any hooks and cleaned up anything that might cause a problem first.

Answer (score 0):

for me this works very well

```
TCHAR DllPath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
GetModuleFileName((HINSTANCE) &__ImageBase, DllPath, _countof(DllPath));

wchar_t dir[_MAX_DIR] = {0};
wchar_t drive[_MAX_DRIVE] = {0};
wchar_t fName[_MAX_FNAME] = {0};
wchar_t ext[_MAX_EXT] = {0};
_wsplitpath_s(DllPath, &drive[0], _MAX_DRIVE, &dir[0], _MAX_DIR, &fName[0], _MAX_FNAME, &ext[0],
              _MAX_EXT);

HMODULE hModLib = GetModuleHandle(fName);
FreeLibrary(hModLib);
```